# Linear second order PDE with Differential Operator

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, differential

I have a question about how to interpret this equation:

D(xDy)-3Dy+2/x*y=1

I think it is a second order linear PDE and have simplified it to:
y''x+y'(x'-3)+2/x*y=1
However, I'm not sure whether y and x depends on a third variable (like `t`). Moreover, I think it might be possible to factorize the equation or maybe tranform it into a ODE. However, I have only learn to solve ODE's yet.

Guidance is strongly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Casper

Comment: You need to use Latex for your maths text. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You also need to specify what you have tried (i.e separation of variables, ansatz etc.) and what you mean by some of your terms (i.e is $D$ a partial differential operator like $\partial_{x} + \partial_{y}$ or is it just an ordinary differential operator like $d/dx$) because as it stands it is incomprehensible.

Comment: That's kind of my problem. I haven't learned anything about this in school and I don't know what the symbols represents...

Comment: I think in this case $D = d/dx$, $x$ is an independent variable and $y = y(x)$ is a dependent variable, in which case your problem is an _ordinary_ differential equation, not a partial differential equation. That means the equation you got $$xy''-2y'+\frac{2}{xy}=1$$ is correct. Note that this is a _nonlinear_ ODE though.

Comment: Thank you! This is much easier to solve :)

Comment: I don't understand how to format the code, but this is what the homogenous solution looks like: y=C_1x^1+C_2x^2. However, now I need to find a particular solution with the right side = 1/x. This is a little bit trickier. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Without other informations ( and if I well interpret) it seems the equation:
$$
(xy')' -3y'+\frac{2}{xy}=1
$$
because $D$ is usually the symbol for the derivative operator. So, with $y=y(x)$ becomes:
$$
y'+xy''-3y'+\frac{2}{xy}=1
$$
that is a non-linear second order ODE.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! This must be the case. I'm sorry that I didn't format the code.